Windows emoji input always gender-specific?
When I open the Windows 10 emoji input (Win+.) and type "shrug", it offers me the male (‍♂️) and female (‍♀️) variant of the shrug emoji. (Technically  + ZWJ + ♂️/♀️.)

Is there a way to get it to offer the plain shrug emoji () as well?
